# Dynamically modify object property typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following typescript function, the purpose of this function is to modify the property of an object dynamically :

```
const test = (data: any, propertyName: keyof Test1, x: Test1) => {
    x[propertyName] = data;
}
```

Here is the "Test1 type"

```
type Test1 = {
    test: string;
    test1: number;
    test2: string;
}
```

In my "test" function, it gives me the following error :

> Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'

I guess the problem comes from the type of "data" but I don't know how I can change it.
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell TypeScript that the type of `data` is `Test1[propertyName]`:

```
const test = <K extends keyof Test1>(data: Test1[K], propertyName: K, x: Test1) => {
    x[propertyName] = data;
};
```

You can't use `Test1[propertyName]` directly, `Test1[typeof propertyName]` won't work because that's the same as `Test1[keyof Test1]`, so you need a generic to retain the type information of `propertyName` and use it later for the type of `data`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YB4DSN4A8FgBMIYBreATxADMYAVRKARgD4AKAgQyg4C46HGAbQwBdADQwADgCcQk+NKjkAchwC28Phgk4+9aIwCUKZjADeAWABQMWzByCZchUtUaRKGJ24BuawF9rayV5fgNPSxs7BGg+aGkASzAAcz8o2ximPjAAVzUAIwU0uzgGACY4qESUtMCrYIZWACImiSbM1vNrEsy+FrFu6IE+AAYB9NLoCph+gMMgA)